# Postgresql - inner column header showing up as "?column?"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE mail(id UUID UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), mailbox VARCHAR(32), mail jsonb);
```

This is how the data is inserted into the table:

```
INSERT INTO mail(mailbox, mail) VALUES ('sent','{"to":{"name":"Shandra Rheam","email":"srheam0@myspace.com"},"from":{"name":"CSE183 Student","email":"cse183student@ucsc.edu"},"received":"2020-11-17T23:17:19Z","sent":"2020-11-14T17:09:17Z"}');
```

If I try:

```
SELECT id, mail->\'to\' FROM mail
```

I get this:

```
{
  "id": "d0c7e73e-20ab-4c0e-b4fd-f687ec082eb6",
  "?column?": {
    "name": "Shandra Rheam",
    "email": "srheam0@myspace.com"
  }
}
```

Why is the column showing up as ?column? instead of "to"?

Answer (score 1):

Your column isn't a column, but an expression. If you want to give that expression a name, you need to use a column alias

```
select id, mail -> 'to' as "to"
from mail;
```

Comment: Ah, I should've realized. Thank you!